# How to update Window form UI after setting CurrentUICulture?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I tried to set CurrentUICulture of the application at run time. However, the menu items in my forms remained unchanged. Do I have to do something additional to changing CurrentUICulture?

Comment: How are you doing it and when ?

Comment: I am setting it on a menu click

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ripped from a google search result: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/468556-change-currentuiculture-controls-doesnt-refresh

> Change "CurrentUICulture" will not automatically take effect in all UI control.
>
> Change "CurrentUICulture" just affect some APIs which are releated to localization.  For example, "System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(.. .)", then it will use the current "CurrentUICulture" to load suitable string resources.
>
> For Windows.Form UI control, you need to reload all the resource strings after change the "CurrentUICulture".

Assuming your resources are actually localized (note that you have to do this manually - nothing will do it for you automatically), you might be able to set the UI culture before showing your first Window.  E.g. in `Main`.

**Edit:**

Also, make sure you set the `CurrentUICulture` on the UI thread.

Here's some example code for how to refresh your UI (again, stolen from the link at the top of this answer):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang); //my selected lang from menu

ReloadControlString();

//...

private void ReloadControlString()
{
    System.Resources.ResourceManager resources = new 
    System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(FormMain));

    this.menuApp.Text = resources.GetString("menuApp.Text");
}
```

You can probably grab some of this from `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: I got that this function does not do automatically. But isn't there any function which I have to call to update all the resources

Comment: @Varun: Check that thread.  It is a manual process (although you might be able to steal some of the generated code from `InitializeComponent()`).

Comment: Nice anonymous downvote.  Care to explain?  Maybe add your own answer?

Answer (score 12):

Late to the party again. But here's a solution I came up with:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form {

    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void mnuCultureEnglish_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "en-US" );
        Controls.Clear();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void mnuCultureGerman_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "de-DE" );
        Controls.Clear();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a similar way to do for a WPF application. I don't see Controls.Clear() there.

Comment: @ChandraMohan Sorry, I haven't messed with WPF yet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have used VS or a compatible utility to create the .resx files:

```
var crm = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(My_Form));
crm.ApplyResources(this.my_button, "my_button");
//    etc ...
```

This might save you some manual labor in setting all localizable properties manually, and also having to use the GetXXX(string) overloads.

Answer (score 1):

At least you can try this cycle after you changed an CurrentUICulture:

```
foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
        {
            resources.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can u please try this below mentioned code i think this will help you out of it.

```
CultureInfo _cinfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _cinfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = _cinfo;

//After changing the Culture just access the value of relevant culture through resource file
label1.text = CommonResource.Ready;
```