# Change localization at execution WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, localization

I have a WPF application that I want it to be two languages. I duplicated my `Resources.resx` and built my two languages like this:

[image]

So when I first load my `MainApplication`  I do this:

```
Properties.Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

before the

```
InitializeComponent();
```

So everything is loaded in the desired language. Now I want to go the obvious step further, and I designed a `Select language` on my application:

[image]

Any idea on how to reload the interface for the different languages at **execution time**?

**EDIT:**

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization?msg=4490202#xx4490202xx) link, and seems to work. But I have a problem. When I try to find the `Resources x:key` it launches an error... It says `ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException`. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750583/resourcereferencekeynotfoundexception-declared-on-dictionary-xaml) to check my mistake.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661661/how-to-update-window-form-ui-after-setting-currentuiculture

Comment: remark: CultureInfo is per thread. dont forget that

Comment: Actually that didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization) interesting link.

Answer (score 3):

You want to change the culture for the UI thread, this should work:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```