# ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException declared on Dictionary.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have an `ObjectDataProvider` declared on a dictionary:

```
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources"
        ObjectType="{x:Type const:CultureResources}" 
        MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>
```

And I have a class that wants to find it like this:

```
m_provider = (ObjectDataProvider) App.Current.FindResource("Resources");
```

But when it tries to find the Resource, it launches the error

```
ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException
```

And can't find my resource... Here you have an image on how my project is divided:

[image]

The `Default.xaml` is my default dictionary.

So, why I can't find my `Resources` element defined on my dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to answer my question, because it was such a weird thing...

At first, I need to say that I had to add my `Dictionary.xaml` to my `App.xaml`:

```
    <Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="../themes/Default.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

For some reason, it wasn't enough to call it on my `MainWindow.xaml`. So I erased it from my `MainWindow.xaml` and added it to `App.xaml`, but I couldn't have them inserted in both sides. That was the part that I couldn't see clearly...